# Find the other relationship in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a big function which has many others functions, (But I can't have all those functions because make a wrong with my others scripts) therefore I only need the functions which make the action which I need; recently I was helped to find a function, but I think which miss other function which Hide the content, and show a button that I need. When I run the script works well, but doesn't show a button and too isn't hidden that bar when you return to the initial position. I tested the big script only for know if there is my mistake and elementally yep.

The big script you can find this here and too the example of what I'm trying to do [See the code and example](https://www.charliehenry.london/hchelp)

You can take a look of what I'm trying to do on this image and the problem:
[See Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG0AT.png)

My current script is this, works very well, but miss those two details which are into the big script. Please help me.

```
// JavaScript Document

;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var docHeight = jQuery(document).height();
        var winHeight = jQuery(window).height();
        var scrollPercent = (scrollTop) / (docHeight - winHeight);
        var scrollPercentRounded = Math.round(scrollPercent * 100);
        jQuery('#post_indicator').css('width', scrollPercentRounded + '%');
    });
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        if (jQuery('#pp_fixed_menu').val() == 1)

        {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() >= 200) {
                jQuery('.header_style_wrapper .above_top_bar').hide();
                jQuery('.extend_top_contact_info').hide();
                jQuery('.top_bar').addClass('scroll');
                jQuery('#post_info_bar').addClass('scroll');
            } else if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
                jQuery('.header_style_wrapper .above_top_bar').show();
                jQuery('.extend_top_contact_info').show();
                jQuery('#custom_logo img').removeClass('zoom');
                jQuery('#custom_logo img').css('maxHeight', '');
                jQuery('#custom_logo').css('marginTop', parseInt(logoMargin) + 'px');
                jQuery('#menu_wrapper div .nav > li > a').css('paddingTop', menuPaddingTop + 'px');
                jQuery('#menu_wrapper div .nav > li > a').css('paddingBottom', menuPaddingBottom + 'px');;
                jQuery('.top_bar').removeClass('scroll');
                jQuery('#post_info_bar').removeClass('scroll');
            }
        } else {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() >= 200) {
                jQuery('.header_style_wrapper').addClass('nofixed');
            } else {
                jQuery('.header_style_wrapper').removeClass('nofixed');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: better to toggle class (name it like, scrolled-out) on body and use css to switch other elements visibility/behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show button (arrow) you need to add it in your html then you can use this script:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

// JavaScript Document

;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var docHeight = jQuery(document).height();
        var winHeight = jQuery(window).height();
        var scrollPercent = (scrollTop) / (docHeight - winHeight);
        var scrollPercentRounded = Math.round(scrollPercent * 100);
        jQuery('#post_indicator').css('width', scrollPercentRounded + '%');
    });



     jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var calScreenWidth = jQuery(window).width();
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            jQuery('#toTop').stop().css({
                opacity: 0.5,
                "visibility": "visible"
            }).animate({
                "visibility": "visible"
            }, {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: "easeOutExpo"
            });
        } else if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
            jQuery('#toTop').stop().css({
                opacity: 0,
                "visibility": "hidden"
            }).animate({
                "visibility": "hidden"
            }, {
                duration: 1500,
                easing: "easeOutExpo"
            });
        }
    });
    jQuery('#toTop, .hr_totop').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
    });


    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery('#pp_fixed_menu').val() == 1)

        {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() >= 200) {
                jQuery('.header_style_wrapper .above_top_bar').hide();
                jQuery('.extend_top_contact_info').hide();
                jQuery('.top_bar').addClass('scroll');
                jQuery('#post_info_bar').addClass('scroll');
            } else if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
                jQuery('.header_style_wrapper .above_top_bar').show();
                jQuery('.extend_top_contact_info').show();
                jQuery('#custom_logo img').removeClass('zoom');
                jQuery('#custom_logo img').css('maxHeight', '');
                jQuery('#custom_logo').css('marginTop', parseInt(logoMargin) + 'px');
                jQuery('#menu_wrapper div .nav > li > a').css('paddingTop', menuPaddingTop + 'px');
                jQuery('#menu_wrapper div .nav > li > a').css('paddingBottom', menuPaddingBottom + 'px');;
                jQuery('.top_bar').removeClass('scroll');
                jQuery('#post_info_bar').removeClass('scroll');
            }
        } else {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() >= 200) {
                jQuery('.header_style_wrapper').addClass('nofixed');
            } else {
                jQuery('.header_style_wrapper').removeClass('nofixed');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

when you scroll up, the bar not hide again ?? i test here with this small script and its hide it when i scroll up